# Silex: how to getHost to set $app['debug']

Tags: silex, http-request

Just after instantiating my new Silex\Application, I'd like to conditionally set $app['debug'] depending upon whether it finds itself on my DEV domain or my PROD domain.

I'm currently doing:

```
$app = new Application();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

if ($request->getHost() == 'production.mydomain') { // PRODuction
    $app['debug'] = false;
} else { // DEVelopment
    $app['debug'] = true;
}
```

According to http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#example-post-route

> The current request is automatically injected by Silex to the Closure
>   thanks to the type hinting. It is an instance of Request, so you can
>   fetch variables using the request get method.

But for reasons I don't understand, the current request doesn't seem to be available in the context where I need it to set $app['debug'], which is why I am instantiating a copy with the static createFromGlobals. It all seems a bit wasteful.

Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just after instantiating your Application it's still is not set up. It doesn't start handling the actual request until you call `run()` on it.

Try setting debug in an app-level before middleware.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.

I was using $app['debug'] as an argument:

ExceptionHandler::register($app['debug']);

and I don't think it's possible or makes sense to do that in a before middleware.

Comment: Nope, doesn't really make sense. I've always set up debug via a config file or an env variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode it in the bootstrap using `$_SERVER` global :

```
$debug = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
        && 'production.mydomain' === $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
        ? false : true;

$app = new Application(['debug' => $debug]);

$app->run(); // calls Request::createFromGlobals()
```